# How to securely manage my own custom claims alongside Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, google-cloud-firestore, express-jwt

I've used Firebase Auth to manage user logins on my app, and custom claims for their roles and permissions for each organization they belong to.

The problem is that when a user belongs to several organizations, **the custom claims exceed the 1,000 characters length limit set by Firebase Authentication**.

For the client, I can make an API call with the ID token, and respond with his/her claims. But for my gateway, it means I now need to query my database at each user request. It defeats the point of JWT at all.

**How can I embed custom claims in a safe way?**

- Desktop Client: ReactJS + Firebase SDK
- API Gateway: Express on NodeJS
- Backend: Firestore for user metadata

Comment: Usually the keys and values of custom claims are very short, and you should not run into this limit. What are you storing as the customer claims? Did you consider using shorter keys/values to keep the claims/tokens short? This is also important, since the claims are encoded in the JWT, which is sent with each request/connection.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you are correct, saved a lot using one-letter keys and removing useless data from it... and I re-inflate the keys and the data on the API Gateway as soon as it's decoded.

Comment: I always assume this is the reason for the three letter keys in standard JWT properties too: all the little bits add up to quite some bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the keys and values of custom claims are very short, and you should not run into this limit. Short keys and values are important, since the claims are encoded in the JWT, which is sent with each request/connection.

You are likely storing readable, meaningful values in your token now. I'd recommend using shorter "codes" as the keys/values of your claims, similar to the three letter default properties of a JWT. That will keep your token size under control, and should bring you back under the limit unless really have a lot of claims.

Comment: How will we capture access for docs in multiple root level collections (e.g. orgs collection)? Given that each doc id will take approx 20 bytes and that roles need to be stored too, a user would be restricted to less than 50 docs. Is it possible to overcome this limit? Is overwriting the custom claim whenever user switches to a different org a good idea?